# Make TreeNode not selectable but still functional

Tags: c#, winforms, treenode

I initialize the component in the designer code:

```
private void InitializeComponent(){
    this.treeViewCategory.Name = "treeViewCategory";
    this.treeViewCategory.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(287, 303);
    this.treeViewCategory.TabIndex = 14;
    this.treeViewCategory.DoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.treeViewCategory_TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler);  
}
```

Outside the designer, I modify it:

```
this.treeViewCategory.Update();
TreeNode node = this.treeViewCategory.Nodes.Add("Node 1");
node.Name = "Node 1";
node.Nodes.Add("Node 1-Child");
node = this.treeViewCategory.Nodes.Add("Node 2");
node.Name = "Node 2";
node.Nodes.Add("Node 2-Child 1");
node.Nodes.Add("Node 2-Child 2");
this.treeViewCategory.ExpandAll();
this.treeViewCategory.EndUpdate();
```

I want Node 1 and Node 2 to be functional but not selectable. So clicking on either Node 1 or Node 2 would expand/contract the branch, but the node itself is not highlighted.

```
private void treeViewCategory_TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    TreeView treeView = (TreeView)sender;
    TreeNode treeNode = eventArgs.Node; // parent or child
    String nodeText = treeNode.Text;

    // if parent node
    if (nodeText.Contains("Node 1") || nodeText.Contains("Node 2")) {
        // don't select the node

    }
    else {  // child

    }
}
```

In  `treeViewCategory_TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler`, I can distinguish between parent and child, but I see nothing that does what I want it do.

[image: Parent node highlighted]

Comment: Do not modify the designer code!

Comment: Can't you just select the child node in the event? And what are you planning to do about selecting the node with the keyboard?

Comment: @TaW: Where do you see the designer code being modified in my example?

Comment: @stuartd: I'm not following you when you say "just select the child node". When the user clicks on a node, be it parent or child, the node is highlighted. I've added an image of the parent being highlighted upon clicking on it. Only the child nodes are valid values to be selected, so I don't want the parent to be selected/highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a handler for the treeview's `BeforeSelect` event, and cancel the selection there.

```
//  Add unselectable nodes to this collection when you create them
private List<TreeNode> _unselectableNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

private void treeViewCategory_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_unselectableNodes.Contains(e.Node))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as noted in comments, this doesn't *prevent* selection so much as revert it when the user releases the mouse button. My preference would be for the `BeforeSelect` event to happen entirely *before* selection takes place. But there's probably a reason for it.

Handler setup, if you're not doing it via the form builder. This should go in the constructor for your Form. No need for the delegate constructor if `treeViewCategory_BeforeSelect` has the correct return and parameter types.

```
this.treeViewCategory.BeforeSelect += treeViewCategory_BeforeSelect;
```

Node creation:

```
TreeNode node = this.treeViewCategory.Nodes.Add("Node 1");
node.Name = "Node 1";
_unselectableNodes.Add(node);

node.Nodes.Add("Node 1-Child");

node = this.treeViewCategory.Nodes.Add("Node 2");
node.Name = "Node 2";
_unselectableNodes.Add(node);
```

Comment: This is the line to add the handle to the control: `this.treeViewCategory.BeforeSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventHandler(this.treeViewCategory_BeforeSelect);`
This works and has the unfortunate effect the node being highlighted (and then reverting to the previously selected node). What terrible design.

Comment: @AlLelopath I agree. The selection reversion bit is ugly. "Before" should mean before.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tag property of the node.
The Tag can carry any kind of object.

```
// for unselectable
...
 node0.Tag = false;
...

// for selectable
...
node1.Tag = true;
...
```

in the selection event you can simply:

```
if ((bool)node.Tag)
  { ... }
```